# Use the Pythagorean triangle rule for the depth of each corner point

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I am doing camera calibration using OpenCV and I can get the camera matrix and projection matrix. But I need to use the Pythagorean triangle rule for the depth of each corner point of the checkerboard. I am new to open cv and have no idea how to deal with. Below is my code and appreciate it if you can help me. The distance from my camera to the checkerboard object is 20000mm.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Find Chessboard Corners
SizeOfChessBoard = (8,6)
SizeOfFrame = (1440,1080)



#Terminatin Criteria
TerminationCriteria= (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)


#Getting object points prepared, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
ObjectPoint = np.zeros((SizeOfChessBoard[0] * SizeOfChessBoard[1], 3), np.float32)
ObjectPoint[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:SizeOfChessBoard[0],0:SizeOfChessBoard[1]].T.reshape(-1,2)

size_of_chessboard_squares_mm = 30
ObjectPoint = ObjectPoint * size_of_chessboard_squares_mm


#Providing arrays to save object and image points obtained from all the available images
#Object point and image point arrays are 3 dimensional point in real world 2 dimensional point in image plane respectively.
ObjectPoints = []
ImagePoints = []


images = glob.glob('myimages\*.jpg')

for image in images:

    img = cv.imread(image)
    grayScaleImage = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #Finding the chessboard corners
    CameraCalibrated, Corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayScaleImage, SizeOfChessBoard, None)

    # If it found chess board corners, after refining them add object points, image points
    if CameraCalibrated == True:

        ObjectPoints.append(ObjectPoint)
        NewCorners = cv.cornerSubPix(grayScaleImage, Corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), TerminationCriteria)
        ImagePoints.append(Corners)

        # Draw chess board corners and display them
        cv.drawChessboardCorners(img, SizeOfChessBoard, NewCorners, CameraCalibrated)
        RGB_img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        plt.imshow(RGB_img)
        plt.show()


cv.destroyAllWindows()

#Let's do calibration
CameraCalibrated, CameraMatrix, DistortionParam, RotationVectors, TranslationVectors = cv.calibrateCamera(ObjectPoints, ImagePoints, SizeOfFrame, None, None)
np.savez('CameraParams.npz', CameraMatrix=CameraMatrix, DistortionParam=DistortionParam, RotationVectors=RotationVectors, TranslationVectors=TranslationVectors)
print("CameraCalibrated: ", CameraCalibrated)
print("\nCamera Matrix: \n", CameraMatrix)
print("\nDistortion Parameters: \n", DistortionParam)

print("\nRotation Vectors: \n", RotationVectors)

print("\nTranslation Vectors: \n", TranslationVectors)

R = cv.Rodrigues(RotationVectors[0])[0]
T = TranslationVectors[0]
RT = np.concatenate([R,T], axis=-1)
P=np.matmul(CameraMatrix, RT)

print("\nProjection Matrix: \n", P)

#From documentation is opencv, we can take an image and undistort it. 
# OpenCV comes with two methods for doing this. 
# However first, we can refine the camera matrix based on a free scaling parameter using cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(). 
# If the scaling parameter alpha=0, it returns undistorted image with minimum unwanted pixels. 
# So it may even remove some pixels at image corners. If alpha=1, all pixels are retained with some extra black images. 
# This function also returns an image ROI which can be used to crop the result.

img = cv.imread('myimages/1.jpg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]
newCameraMatrix, RegionOfInterest = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(CameraMatrix, DistortionParam, (w,h), 1, (w,h))

#Method 1: Undistortion using cv.undistort()
# This is the easiest way. Just call the function and use ROI obtained above to crop the result.
distortion = cv.undistort(img, CameraMatrix, DistortionParam, None, newCameraMatrix)

#Let's crop the image
x, y, w, h = RegionOfInterest
distortion = distortion[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv.imwrite('CalibratedResult\caliResult1.jpg', distortion)

# Method 2: Undistortion using Remapping
#This way is a little bit more difficult. First, find a mapping function from the distorted image to the undistorted image. 
#Then use the remap function.
mapx, mapy = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(CameraMatrix, DistortionParam, None, newCameraMatrix, (w,h), 5)
distortion = cv.remap(img, mapx, mapy, cv.INTER_LINEAR)

#Let's crop the image
x, y, w, h = RegionOfInterest
distortion = distortion[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv.imwrite('CalibratedResult\caliResult2.jpg', distortion)

#Let's compute Re-projection error
mean_error = 0

for i in range(len(ObjectPoints)):
    NewImagePoints, _ = cv.projectPoints(ObjectPoints[i], RotationVectors[i], TranslationVectors[i], CameraMatrix, DistortionParam)
    error = cv.norm(ImagePoints[i], NewImagePoints, cv.NORM_L2)/len(NewImagePoints)
    mean_error += error

print( "total error: {}".format(mean_error/len(ObjectPoints)) )
```

Answer (score -2):

if (found)
{
cornerSubPix(gray, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
drawChessboardCorners(gray, board_sz, corners, found);
}

```
    imshow("image", img);
    imshow("corners", gray);

    k = waitKey(1);
    if (found)
    {
        k = waitKey(0);
    }
    if (k == 27)
    {
        break;
    }
    if (k == ' ' && found !=0)
    {
        image_points.push_back(corners);
        object_points.push_back(obj);
        printf ("Corners stored\n");
        success++;

        if (success >= numBoards)
        {
            break;
```

Comment: Where is  Pythagorean triangle rule in the code?